# Discrete sample with no sampling rate - Freq. space and power

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, matlab-figure

[graph 1 - signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lh1S.png)
[graph 2 - freq space and power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNz1A.png)

Could someone help me figure out how to get the second graph from this signal using Matlab functions?
x = r(n+6) - r(n+4) + r(n+2) - 2.*r(n) + r(n-4)

All the documentation I can find applies only to signals with known sampling time/rate, but I have the sample numbers, nothing else. How can I apply FFT with no known frequency?

I've tried to use the FFT functions to plot the normalized freq. and power in dB, but nothing is really working. Matlab's Data Analyzer won't allow me to set samples from -8:6 either, only 0:14.